# Trouble using puppeteer in a react-electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, puppeteer

I am making an electron app in react. I need to use puppeteer. The following function when used in the main process works correctly as intended. But when I use this function in the App.js React component, I get an error saying that waitForNavigation is not a function. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
//App.js function
const puppeteer = window.require('puppeteer');
  async function login(username, password) {
    try {
      setServerMessage("Logging in.");
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
      const page = (await browser).newPage();
      (await page).goto("https://codeforces.com/enter?back=%2F");
      await page.waitForSelector("#handleOrEmail");
      await page.type("#handleOrEmail", username);
      await page.type("#password", password);
      setServerMessage("Logged in successfully.");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Puppeteer error, ", e);
    }
  };
```

```
//Main process function
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  async function login(username, password) {
    try {
    
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
      const page = (await browser).newPage();
      (await page).goto("https://codeforces.com/enter?back=%2F");
      await page.waitForSelector("#handleOrEmail");
      await page.type("#handleOrEmail", username);
      await page.type("#password", password);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Puppeteer error, ", e);
    }
  };
```